# samba is not starting/working

Tags: linux, networking, debian, samba

I've tried a lot of things and I am at the end of my wits here. I ask humbly for help.

Basically `smbd` daemon refuses to start

I run `sudo service samba restart`

```
   Stopping Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.   
   Starting Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.
```

Everything seems fine but `service samba status` shows

```
  nmbd is running. 
  could not access PID file for smbd ... failed!
```

- `pgrep -l mbd` show that only `nmbd` process is running

  > 2962 nmbd
- I have no firewall setup
- `testparm -s /etc/samba/smb.conf` show that everything is ok

  > Loaded services file OK
- network is up and everything (I can ping google at least)
  f

I even reinstalled samba , rebooted my computer

It used to work, now it does not

The only changes that I recall that I made since

- I installed nfs (it cannot be that, at work nfs and samba are working with no problem)
- I change the router ip address and dhcp address range (from 192.168.0.XXX to 192.168.1.XXX)
- and setup static ip address to the linux (debian) running samba (192.168.1.102)

`/var/log/samba/*` logs are showing nothing, literaly no new line.

Comment: Did you check to see if the PID file exists, and/or if the location for the PID file exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to try answering, but please be patient as I am new to sysadmin and this site.

Since you say that you reinstalled samba, I'm wondering if there's not something outside of that service as a possible problem.  I'm wondering 3 things:
First, update your system totally
    `yum update all`
Second, check what ports are being used to see if anything could conflict with samba
    `netstat - tupan`
also try this for smb specific ports to see if anything else is on that port
    `netstat -tulpn | grep 445`
and double-check to make sure your firewall isn't on after a reboot
    `service iptables stop`
also try using nmblookup to find the server.
Third, run through this checklist (if you haven't)
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/diagnosis.html

For the smbd to be failing, it's something in the tcp/ip connection from the samba server.   But smbd may be running from somewhere else already.

Comment: Thank you!.Of course I should have check [the documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/diagnosis.html) Your link helped me. It turns out that I have forgotten to change the permitted interfaces (192.168.0 to 192.168.1) in smb.conf